# AES Cpu Consumption: What's cheaper? To encrypt/decrypt 1024 bytes in AES-256 or 512 in AES-128 and 512 in AES-256

Tags: encryption, cryptography, security, aes

I am trying to figure out if it is worth using differential privacy on some data that I need to secure.

So what is less CPU intensive? Encrypt the whole data in AES-256 or encrypt parts of it in AES-256 and other parts in AES-128.

Is the difference significant? Mixing schemes will require the generation of more keys and ivs for each different level of encryption.

Any references? Comments?

Comment: Have you [thoroughly searched for an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/search) before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps _you_ get a more specific and relevant answer!  See also [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and [What makes a good question?](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints)

Comment: @DanPichelman Yes, however, given that you clearly know of the existence of such answers with the information that I require. You could have, instead of writing 6 lines providing 3 un-requested links, given one to the answer containing the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encrypt everything with AES-128 if you care about performance. AES-256 is not much more secure in practice, since 128-bit keys cannot be brute forced anywhere in the foreseeable future. Also see [this blog post](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2009/07/another_new_aes.html), where Bruce Schneier recommends against using AES-256.

Comment: Thanks! I found several claims, also one by Schneider that 256 is about 40% slower. However, I can't find any real sources. I have been asked to look into using differential privacy schemes to reduce CPU consumption and thus extend battery life. But I can't really find much on sources, it's too early so I have no HW to test on...

Comment: @unixsnob You should just encrypt everything with AES-128. AES-256 offers no practical advantage over AES-128, since neither can be cracked (and in fact, AES-256 seems to have theoretical weaknesses that AES-128 does not have). More bits doesn't always mean more security.

Comment: @ntoskrnl Those "weaknesses" don't apply to any proper use of AES. They just mean that you shouldn't try to build a secure hashfunction out of AES.