# IIS w3wp high CPU when AES256 implemented replacing 3DES and AES128

Tags: windows, iis, cpu-usage, kentico

We have an information web site running on Kentico CMS as backend. The server is fairly new (eg HPDL380G8, 2proc 64bit ram)

Recently our security team did vulnerability assessment and requested us to remove 3DES and AES128 SSL encryption, only AES256 was allowed.

After only allowing AES256, our server's CPU spiked up and site slowed down. We reverted with 3DES and AES128 and CPU went back normal.

Just wondering if there anything we miss out on the IIS , windows settings.

Comment: What version of Kentico are you running?

Comment: 9_0_50. but I don't think is a version issue with Kentico.

Comment: Just checking as you didn't specify it in your original post.  Also, there are hotfixes in v9 and v10 which relate to high CPU usage so yes, it could be a version issue but I believe Trevor hit the nail on the head with his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in this other [Stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16899858/aes-cpu-consumption-whats-cheaper-to-encrypt-decrypt-1024-bytes-in-aes-256-or), the AES256 will have a VERY big CPU impact, this has little to nothing to do with Kentico, it's a generic fact that the greater the encryption, usually takes more CPU to encrypt/decrypt.  I would reference the blog article in the other stack overflow question and push to go back to 128